# R Take First String and Fill It For Group

Tags: r, data.table

```
DATA = data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                  "TIME" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2),
"ANIM" = c('CAT','FOX','RABIT','DOG','FOX','BUNNY','FOX','DOG'))
DATA$WANT = c('CAT','CAT','CAT','DOG','DOG','DOG','FOX','FOX')
```

I have 'DATA' and wish to add variable 'WANT' which takes the first 'ANIM' for each 'ID'. I wish for a data.table solution as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `na.locf` from `zoo` and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
setDT(DATA)[, ANIM := na.locf0(na.locf0(na_if(ANIM, "")), fromLast = TRUE), ID]
```

With the updated version, we can do `first`

```
setDT(DATA)[order(TIME), WANT := first(ANIM), ID]
```

Comment: thank you so much i am unable to upvote you because i am new

Comment: thanks so much. will first know to take it by TIME or do I need to first sort the data

Comment: @ajpat if it is not sorted, specify the `order(TIME)` in `i`. updated

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to replace the empty string in `ANIM` with NA values thanks to the function `na_if`, and then use the `fill` function within groups

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DATA %>%
  mutate(ANIM = na_if(ANIM, '')) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(ANIM, .direction = "downup")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID ANIM 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 CAT  
# 2     1 CAT  
# 3     1 CAT  
# 4     2 FOX  
# 5     2 FOX  
# 6     2 FOX  
# 7     3 DOG  
# 8     3 DOG
```

Comment: Thanks so much do you know a datatable solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm not familiar with `data.table`.  I suggest you to edit your question specifying that you would like a ○6data.table` solution

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse`, use `fill`, after converting your "" strings to NA

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA <- tibble("ID"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3, 3),
                  "ANIM" = c('CAT','','','','FOX','','','DOG'))
DATAWANT = DATA %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(ANIM = as.character(ANIM),
         ANIM = ifelse(ANIM == "", NA_character_, ANIM)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(ANIM,  .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 2 
     ID ANIM 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 CAT  
2     1 CAT  
3     1 CAT  
4     2 FOX  
5     2 FOX  
6     2 FOX  
7     3 DOG  
8     3 DOG
```

Comment: I believe that `ANIM` should respect the groups identified by variable `ID`. In this case it doesn't happen for rows 4 and 7

Comment: @David T Thanks so much do you know a datatable solution?

Comment: ajpat - sorry, no I don't much do `datatable`. @ric-s - you're right! and I missed it.  I've edited and corrected.